# Getting Unknown Error while trying to Post Data in angular

Tags: angular, go

I am trying to send an HTTP post request from my component typescript page to create a record. But I am getting an HttpErrorResponse error.
[image]

**TypescriptFile**

```
    onSubmit(form) {
    this.http.post('/api/providerapplication', JSON.stringify(form.value))
      .subscribe(result => {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you are not sending the oauth token via postman. Determine how the oauth token is sent and make sure it is sent in accordance with a typical logged in request. e.g. I believe oauth token is typically sent in the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you have provided I can deduct that your backend application which is responsible for handling `/api/providerapplication` endpoint is somehow misconfigured or wrongly informs the user about the problem. This HTTP endpoint returns an error message which is a string representation of an error received from the internal client. The client cannot obtain the token to communicate with some external service. If the token is submitted by the user (from a browser) your backend should respond with error code 401 in this case instead of 500, since the token is missing. If the token is obtained based on credentials from the application configuration by the application itself you need to correct the configuration.

It is worth mentioning that it is not a good pattern to blindly copy all the information from internal errors and send it to the user, as this may reveal confidential information.